# iOS Device communication

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ftp

I am keen to get some apps built that can communicate with other devices/ web etc. i have played around with FTP and can get so far. But what is the best way to do this? We don't have any Servers with databases etc, but do have a site that we are currently uploading and downloading files to.

can anyone suggest a good/ better way to get the device to send/ receive files?

thanks

sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's HTTP communication you're wanting to do, the simplest and most powerful tool is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

HTTP is the protocol your web browser uses to talk to web servers. If you have a site you're storing and downloading files at, it's almost certainly HTTP you're talking to it.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS device to device communication one can use [Bump API](http://bu.mp/api).

EDIT: I don't know of a generic framework for device <-> server communications, but having built applications that use web services of other providers like [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/search_api), [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/), [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/), I would say the way to go for this is to have [REST based web services](http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html) which exchange data in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format.

Comment: can that be used to get files to the device from a pc or server?

Comment: communicating with the server is more important than communicating with other devices - any suggestions?